# Two right joins

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to select all records in TABLEC and its equivalent value in TABLEA or TABLEB using right join. I am using MYSQL 5.5.47.

--Table data as follows

```
TABLEA          TABLEB      TABLEC  
ID  FNAME       ID  MNAME   ID  LNAME
0   ANOOP       0   N       0   SINGH
1   BIMA        2   SITA    3   RAJ
4   CIMI        4   B       5   KUMAR
6   RAVI        5   A       6   D
```

--Using below query and trying to select all records in TABLEC and its equivalent value in TABLEA or TABLEB

```
 SELECT A.FNAME, B.MNAME, C.LNAME
 FROM TABLEA AS A 
 RIGHT JOIN TABLEB AS B ON A.ID = B.ID 
 RIGHT JOIN TABLEC AS C ON C.ID = B.ID
```

--I am getting the following result

```
ANOOP           N       SINGH                   
NULL            NULL    RAJ                 
NULL            A       KUMAR                   
***NULL***      NULL    D
```

The highlighted value doesn’t show the value as 'RAVI' instead it shows NULL in MYSQL 5.5.47. I tried to modify the '=' condition in second join related to C & A but still no luck. What am I doing wrong here? How do I get the value 'RAVI' in place of NULL? Any suggestion would be highly helpful.

Comment: add your expected result in question

Comment: table A RIGHT JOIN table B gives 'fetch me all records in table A whose keys match in table B, plus return me all rows of table B". So, in your first join statement itself, Ravi, whose id is 6 and whose id, 6, is not present in table B, is being eliminated. How did we decide we require a right join?

Comment: Are you looking to a full outer join here?  Or do you want to retain only records which appear as last names?

Comment: While in theory every LEFT JOIN has a logically equivalent RIGHT JOIN, in practice RIGHT JOINs are vanishingly rare - in part, I suspect, because, like me, many people find them counter-intuitive.

Comment: Switch to left join. Most people find right join too confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_a;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_b;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS table_c;

CREATE TABLE table_a
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,fname VARCHAR(12) NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_a VALUES
(0,'ANOOP'),
(1,'BIMA'),
(4,'CIMI'),
(6,'RAVI');

CREATE TABLE table_b
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,mname VARCHAR(12) NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_b VALUES
(0,'N'),
(2,'SITA'),
(4,'B'),
(5,'A');

CREATE TABLE table_c
(id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
,lname VARCHAR(12) NULL
);

INSERT INTO table_c VALUES
(0,'SINGH'),
(3,'RAJ'),
(5,'KUMAR'),
(6,'D');

 SELECT a.fname
      , b.mname
      , c.lname 
   FROM table_c c 
   LEFT 
   JOIN table_a a  
     ON a.id = c.id 
   LEFT 
   JOIN table_b b 
     ON b.id = c.id;
+-------+-------+-------+
| fname | mname | lname |
+-------+-------+-------+
| ANOOP | N     | SINGH |
| NULL  | NULL  | RAJ   |
| NULL  | A     | KUMAR |
| RAVI  | NULL  | D     |
+-------+-------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said "select all records in TABLEC and its equivalent value in TABLEA or TABLEB", so you need to join the C with A and C with B. So your need to update your query as :

```
SELECT A.FNAME, B.MNAME, C.LNAME
FROM TABLEC AS C RIGHT JOIN TABLEB AS B
    ON B.ID = C.ID
RIGHT JOIN TABLEA AS A
    ON C.ID = A.ID
```

If you want all the record that exist in A, B and C. The NULL value will shown for the record which doesn't have the value,

```
SELECT  A.FNAME, B.MNAME, C.LNAME
FROM (
TABLEA AS A
LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B ON B.ID = A.ID
)
RIGHT JOIN TABLEC AS C ON ( C.ID = B.ID
OR B.ID = NULL 
OR A.ID = C.ID ) 
WHERE 1
```

Comment: table c does not have ids 2 and 4 so those will be missing in the result.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select all records in TABLEC and its equivalent value in TABLEA or TABLEB using right join. So Table A and B is joined to Table c records. So we need to use Left join(you will get all records of Table C and common records of Table A and B). More info please ref this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))

```
SELECT 
    ifnull(A.FNAME,""), 
    ifnull(B.MNAME,""),
    ifnull(C.LNAME,"")
FROM 
    TABLEA AS A 
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEB AS B
ON 
    A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN 
    TABLEC AS C
ON 
    C.ID = B.ID
```

Comment: table a does not have id 2 and 5 so that will be missing in the result.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you don't have a table that contains all the ids.  So you have to make one. Then you can join from that.

Get all the ids with this query

```
SELECT ID FROM TABLEA
UNION 
SELECT ID FROM TABLEB
UNION 
SELECT ID FROM TABLEC
```

Now we can use this query/table of ids to join the others

```
SELECT A.FNAME, B.MNAME, C.LNAME
FROM (
  SELECT ID FROM TABLEA
  UNION 
  SELECT ID FROM TABLEB
  UNION 
  SELECT ID FROM TABLEC
) I
LEFT JOIN TABLEA A ON I.ID = A.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLEB B ON I.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN TABLEC C ON I.ID = C.ID
```

Of course if you had another table (TABLEID) that had a list of all IDs you could use that instead of the sub-query above.  It might be your model has such a table, but we won't know unless you tell us.

Answer (score 0):

1. Use this works perfectly

```
    SELECT A.FNAME, B.MNAME, C.LNAME
    FROM TABLEC AS C 
    LEFT JOIN TABLEA AS A ON (A.ID = C.ID)
    LEFT JOIN TABLEB AS B ON (B.ID = C.ID)
```